# WPF DataGrid: How to prevent auto change row on enter key pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, keyboard-events

I'm using MVVM pattern in my WPF project, now I'm facing a problem as title mentioned. I found some suggestions is to use `KeyEventArgs.Handled = true;` like this:

```
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter)) || (e.Key.Equals(Key.Return)))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But I want to write it in ViewModel not code-behind of View. This [example](http://www.a2zmenu.com/blogs/silverlight/using-key-event-with-the-mvvm-pattern.aspx) shows the way to handle Key Event with the MVVM pattern but I don't know how to pass `KeyEventArgs` parameter for use.

Can anyone can help me? 
Is this the best way to do that?

Any recommendation or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All code about events interacting with controls should stay in the View. The ViewModel should be the same no matter how you display the data. if it's with a Datagrid, ListView or TextBox is not a concern for the ViewModel.

Comment: Origence is right. In your view model you can code what shall happen if a value changes. But whether a values changes or not should be a matter of a view. Do you want to perform edits in the `DataGrid` at all? Otherwise you could disable it as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766500/4424024

Comment: I understand, it works if I declare an event for a control in view(xaml) then auto-generate an event handler in the code-behind(xaml.cs) but with MVVM, code-behind is not allowed (that's a rule) and my DataGrid can be editable.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily handle enter key press event, I have handled datagrid enter key press event like below code:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.HandleEnterKeyCommand, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
 </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Now, you can write your logic in viewmodel through command.